# unable to find type in interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object

I cannot find the type of the object "history" in the Class, with "any []" there is no problem but I prefer to avoid using it and to have a good typing.

```
interface GameClass{
  history: any[] ////////////Here
  stepNumber:number
  xIsNext:boolean
}

class Game extends React.Component<GameProps,GameClass>{
  constructor(props:GameProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      history: [{ squares: Array(9).fill(null) }], ////////////Here
      stepNumber: 0,
      xIsNext: true
    };
  }
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/hyugato/pen/rNOXwPP?editors=0010)

Thank you

Comment: It seems to be `Array< { squares: any[] } >`. But what type of data do you want to store in `history`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a type for it.

```
interface History {
    squares: number[]; // Not sure what type you want here `number` or `string`
}

interface GameClass{
  history: History[];
  stepNumber: number
  xIsNext: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Thank you hendrixchord that work fine , but i didn't know this way of doing !